# how can i scale up website or scale down depending on screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css, scale

so i made a website that has images multiple textboxes and etc, some user percentage and some use pixels by that i mean they use that to be in the specific place there in right now. So if you connect your laptop to a tv and put the website it will automatically scale up perfectly it just causes the things to be a little blurry but everything is in place. i was wondering how i can add like a function for my website that selects everything in the page and just shrinks it or expands it depending on the screen size, i dont care if it gets blurry after shrinking or expanding. Or if anyone has any other idea on how i can make everything fit to page no matter screen size it would be very helpful.

Comment: You should google for *responsive website* and you will find lots of tutorials on how to do this. This is too broad of a question to be properly answered here. Part of the solution might be [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Comment: so lets say you like a couple pictures and a couple text boxes in a specific position and a specific size, when i plug my laptop to a tv it will automatically scale up and look normal, but if you go on a bigger screen size from another laptop it will look bad and things would be out of position. I was wondering how i could like scale it up like when its connected to the tv. But still thank you i will do that.

Comment: Yes I know what you mean, but trust me this is a very common topic which pretty much any modern website faces and there is a lot to cover starting from selecting the right image formats like svg, to media queries, flexbox, grid etc. . All play a part in this so called responsive web design. You could spend a lot of time on this.

Comment: yes i searched it up a bit and i found out it needed lots of work but i was wondering if i could like scale it up like when you connect it to a tv. But still thankyou for your suggestion

Comment: use vw instead of px XD

Comment: first can you use vw for the size of something and like the position and second will it keep something in the same place no matter how big the screen

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there are multiple ways to make a site responsiv,
the easiest way are the media queries:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background: #fff;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 601px) {
  body {
    background: #ccc;
  }
}
```

This can also be applied to different stylesheets:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/gardener_main.css" media="screen"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/additional.css" media="screen"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/gardener_800.css" media="screen and (min-width: 800px)"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/gardener_799.css" media="screen and (max-width: 799px)"/>
```

They are basicly telling the devices what styles to use for what display size.

For the start you can work through this:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

to get a better understanding of the media query itself.

But! Most somehow tend to forget that you also need to adjust your html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

Depending on how much devices and how much older devices you want to support you can also add a switch that basicly replaces everything:

```
<?php

    $mobrowser = '0'; 
    if (preg_match('/(up.browser|up.link|mmp|symbian|smartphone|midp|wap|phone|android)/i', 
    strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))) {
    $mobrowser++;
    }if ((strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']),'application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml') > 0) or 
    ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE']) 
    or isset($_SERVER['HTTP_PROFILE'])))) {$mobile_browser++;}
    $mobile_ua = strtolower(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 0, 4));
    $mobile_agents = array(
    'w3c ','acs-','alav','alca','amoi','audi','avan','benq','bird','blac',
    'blaz','brew','cell','cldc','cmd-','dang','doco','eric','hipt','inno',
    'ipaq','java','jigs','kddi','keji','leno','lg-c','lg-d','lg-g','lge-',
    'maui','maxo','midp','mits','mmef','mobi','mot-','moto','mwbp','nec-',
    'newt','noki','oper','palm','pana','pant','phil','play','port','prox',
    'qwap','sage','sams','sany','sch-','sec-','send','seri','sgh-','shar',
    'sie-','siem','smal','smar','sony','sph-','symb','t-mo','teli','tim-',
    'tosh','tsm-','upg1','upsi','vk-v','voda','wap-','wapa','wapi','wapp',
    'wapr','webc','winw','winw','xda ','xda-');
    
    if (in_array($mobile_ua,$mobile_agents)) {$mobrowser++;}
    if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['ALL_HTTP']),'OperaMini') > 0) {$mobrowser++;}
    if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),'windows') > 0) {$mobrowser = 0;}
    if ($mobrowser > 0) {
    echo '
    HTML old mobile devices etc
    ';
    }
    else {
    echo '
    HTML desktop
    ';
    }?>
```

With this enormus something you can grab the mobile agents,
but such things are only interesting if you really want to support
historic devices.

Comment: yes i know this but this would take lots and lots of time i was wondering can you just select everything in the body and just make it bigger. if not ill go this way

Comment: Using pre made templates and libarys, it really depends on how much work you want to put into it.

Comment: Can you use VH and VW and if you do what are the downsides to using them

Comment: There are no downsides, just follow thier rules or to say it better use them the right way: https://elementor.com/help/whats-the-difference-between-px-em-rem-vw-and-vh/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to add some css like
@media screen and (min-width: 1240px) {...}

Comment: what will that do

Comment: with css @media screen you can add the min-width and max-width, depending on the device size you want to style. You can test how it looks in browser with inspect element and toggle device toolbar

Comment: do you have like a quick demo with a picture or something so i can see how it works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

[Responsive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oN8C4.jpg)

Here is how you can test it. Just open it in browser, go right click inspect element or f12. I marked with red where you can see that, how it will look on different sizes.